# How to create Flask REST API in front of Elasticsearch server?

Tags: python, rest, flask

I want to expose a functionality of query string search with some optional filters in my Flask RESTful web app. What is the best way to structure this? Should this part be coded manually or there's some fancy framework solution?

Answer (score 0):

when designing API's in flask I'd highly recommend using `MethodViews`

here you can find out more about them and an example

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/views/